# Debian 8.6 - Large file at root called EMPTY

Tags: debian, files, virtual-machine, disk-cleanup, safety

Recently I've been doing some maintenance on a cloud-hosted server I run. My host is DreamHost, specifically their DreamCompute service and the server is running Debian 8.6.

While cleaning up old files, I found a rather suspicious file located in `/` called `EMPTY` with a size of 3.3 GB.

```
<ME>@<SERVER> / % ls -alh
total 3.3G
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root 4.0K Sep 23 11:31 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root 4.0K Sep 23 11:31 ..
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root 4.0K Sep 23 11:20 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Sep 23 11:20 boot
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   30 Aug 24 08:30 config
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root 3.0K Sep 23 11:31 dev
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 3.3G Mar 16  2016 EMPTY <--- ???
drwxr-xr-x 112 root root 4.0K Sep 23 15:15 etc
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root 4.0K Jun  8 10:50 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   36 Apr 11 13:37 initrd.img -> /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   36 Mar 16  2016 initrd.img.old -> /boot/initrd.img-4.3.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root 4.0K Mar 16  2016 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Sep 23 11:20 lib64
drwx------   2 root root  16K Mar 16  2016 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Mar 16  2016 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Mar 16  2016 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root 4.0K Jun 29 09:59 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 157 root root    0 Sep 23 11:31 proc
drwx------  11 root root 4.0K Sep 23 21:18 root
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  820 Sep 24 06:25 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Sep 23 11:20 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Mar 16  2016 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Sep 26 16:52 sys
drwxrwxrwt  13 root root 4.0K Sep 26 16:51 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root 4.0K Apr 16 09:38 usr
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root 4.0K Jun  9 09:26 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   32 Apr 11 13:37 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   32 Mar 16  2016 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.3.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
```

I attempted to use `sed -n '/\S/ p' < EMPTY` to check if the file really was empty of everything except whitespace and it didn't print any output. I then did `sed '/\S/ p' < EMPTY && echo "$?"` to make sure the command didn't crash part way through and it returned 0.

I just want to confirm, though. Is this file safe to delete?

Comment: FWIW, I'd assume that was created for the same purpose e.g. `zerofree` is used for - to write all free filesystem space with zeros so that the server image could be compressed to just the payload data as best as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be safe to delete. I wouldn't delete it immediately though, I would compress it — it should compress very well indeed:

```
gzip -9 EMPTY
```

(or `xz EMPTY` or ...). This should free up most of the 3.3GB, and allow you to restore the file if you later determine something needs it. You can delete the compressed file once you've made sure everything still works (which basically means checking your specific applications still work — nothing in the base system should need such a file).

Comment: The file compressed down to 3.3 MB and I will monitor the system over the next few days to ensure nothing strange happens as a result of this, as you suggest, before removing it entirely. Definitely a better solution than outright deleting the file.